# Decimal to binary conversion program "abort trap: 6" error

Tags: c, runtime-error

I wrote a little program in C to help myself learn converting from decimal to binary. When I run it, it prints out a random number for me to convert and waits for me to enter in the converted number. After I entered the decimal number and press enter it will send my "CONGRATS!" message if I got it right but will also have an error:

> Abort trap: 6

in output even though the program mostly runs fine all the way through the end. I know `Abort trap: 6` has something to do with arrays but I'm not sure besides that. Any ideas? Oh and below is my program.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_NUMBER 256  // random number will fall between 0 and 255
#define BI_NUM_SIZE 8   // represents the 8 spaces needed for each number

/* This function does the exponentiation operation
   to ints and returns an int */
int exponent (int base, int power)
{
    int answer = base, i;
    if (power < 0) {
        printf ("ERROR: no negative numbers as the power "
                "in the exponent function!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if (power == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        for (i = 1; i < power; i++) {
            answer *= base;
        }
        return answer;
    }
}

int main () {

    int number_to_convert, i, j, k;
    char possible_answer[BI_NUM_SIZE];
    char answer[BI_NUM_SIZE];
    char answer_check;
    srand (time (NULL));

    number_to_convert = rand () % MAX_NUMBER;

    // this for loop solves the decimal to binary conversion
    // and stores the character array answer in 'answer';
    // as i decrements for the conversion math j will from 0 to place
    // characters in the answer array
    j = 0;  // allows for indexing through answer[]

    // starts as number_to_convert but gets widled down
    int temp_number = number_to_convert;

    for (i = BI_NUM_SIZE; i > 0; i--) {
        // as part of the
        if (temp_number >= exponent (2, i - 1)) {
            answer[j] = '1';
            temp_number -= exponent (2, i - 1);
        } else {
            answer[j] = '0';
        }
        j++;
    }
    printf ("Convert %3d to binary:\n", number_to_convert);
    printf ("type your answer and press enter:\n");
    scanf ("%s", &possible_answer);

    answer_check = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < BI_NUM_SIZE; i++) {
        if (answer[i] == possible_answer[i]) {
            answer_check++;
        }
    }

    if (answer_check == BI_NUM_SIZE) {
        printf ("CONGRATS! you got it right!\n");
    } else {
        printf ("sorry the answer is ");
        for (i = 0; i < BI_NUM_SIZE; i++) {
            printf ("%c", answer[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since you are learning, strongly suggest you now turn to learning how to use a debugger.

Comment: `#define BI_NUM_SIZE 8`. Strings are NUL terminated in C. You need a buffer of 9 bytes to store a string with 8 characters. Assuming you are entering an 8 digit binary number (it's not clear from your description that that is the expected input).

Comment: regarding this line: `scanf("%s",&possible_answer);`  using '%s' with no max char modifier allows the user to overrun the input buffer ('answer[]') resulting in undefined behaviour, leading to a seg fault event,  1) strongly suggest limiting the number of characters to sizeof(answer)-1.  -1 because scanf() with the '%s' format specifier will always append a NUL byte to the input.  2) check (!=NULL) the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  (In this case, any returned value except 1 indicates some kind of error occurred.

Comment: ...I get a bit tired of all those who do not format their code and expect us to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading information using `scanf` and the *format-specifier* `%s`, `scanf` will read characters until the first *whitepace* is encountered, storing the result as a *nul-terminated* string in the corresponding *pointer* argument given. If you intend to read 8-characters entered by the user into `possible_answer`, then the correct form of the `scanf` call, with the appropriate width limitation, is:

```
scanf ("%8s", possible_answer);
```

(**note:** you do not include an `'&'` in front of `possible_answer` because it is already a *pointer*. You should also check the return to insure 1 successful conversion is made.)

You must provide adequate space for the number of characters to be read `+1` for the *nul-terminating* character. If you intend to read 8-characters into `possible_answer`, you must provide storage for 9-charactes. For example:

```
#define BI_NUM_SIZE 8+1
```

Also note, that will require adjusting all of your loop and test bounds that rely on `BI_NUM_SIZE` below. e.g.:

```
for (i = BI_NUM_SIZE - 1; i > 0; i--) {
...
if (answer_check == BI_NUM_SIZE - 1) {
```

The relevant code with each of the changes included is:

```
    for (i = BI_NUM_SIZE - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        // as part of the
        if (temp_number >= exponent (2, i - 1)) {
            answer[j] = '1';
            temp_number -= exponent (2, i - 1);
        } else {
            answer[j] = '0';
        }
        j++;
    }
    printf ("Convert %3d to binary\n", number_to_convert);
    printf ("answer and press enter: ");
    scanf ("%8s", possible_answer);

    answer_check = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < BI_NUM_SIZE - 1; i++) {
        if (answer[i] == possible_answer[i]) {
            answer_check++;
        }
    }

    if (answer_check == BI_NUM_SIZE - 1) {
        printf ("\nCONGRATS! you got it right!\n\n");
    } else {
        printf ("sorry the answer is   : ");
        for (i = 0; i < BI_NUM_SIZE - 1; i++) {
            printf ("%c", answer[i]);
        }
        putchar ('\n');
    }
    return 0;
```

After you make those changes, your code should work without issue. *note:* you must provide all leading `0's` in your answer as the code is written. e.g.:

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/bincnv
Convert 117 to binary
answer and press enter: 00000001
sorry the answer is   : 01110101

$ ./bin/bincnv
Convert  71 to binary
answer and press enter: 01000111

CONGRATS! you got it right!
```